# Optimising Marksheet Database

Tags: mysql, database-design, innodb, php

1. I am trying to design a database for mark sheet data of a school having different types of exams of different levels or class.
2. Is it possible to have single table where I can store data in string (array serialize PHP) and perform a search based on subjects easily (Maximum/Minimum/Average).

The table look something like this with bit variations-

#### Class 5

```
XXXXX ------ Math ----- Hindi ----- English
Amit -------- 10 ------- 20 ----------31
Alok -------- 10 ------- 20 ----------31
```

#### Class 8

```
XXXXX ------ Math ----- Hindi ----- English ---- Science
Amit -------- 10 ------- 20 ----------31 ----------20
Alok -------- 10 ------- 20 ----------31 ----------23
```

Using PHP's array serialize I will have marks data in string as

```
a:4:{s:4:"math";i:20;s:5:"hindi";i:30;s:7:"english";i:23;s:7:"science";i:10;}
```

Should I have separate table or can I have the condensed table so that database does not become too heavy with too many rows?

Comment: Have you tried JSON structure?

Comment: I have advantage of `serialize` over `JSON`... Although JSON is efficient too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really should not hide the data you want to do arithmetic inside any kind of structure.

Use a table with 4 columns:  class, student, subject, score.

Then things like each student's avg score:

```
SELECT student,
       AVG(score)
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY student;
```

Comment: You are right. But what if data has variable fields or subjects.? How can I handle that?

Comment: "Variable fields"?  Perhaps we need to see some more data, plus more desired output.  The new example(s) should highlight what you are asking.

Comment: Variable fields mean, I need data in variable columns...

Comment: I will need normalisation here to make it efficient.